# How to build a flexible code hierarchy

Tags: c, algorithm, makefile, flexibility

So, I have an algorithm, composed of parameters A, B, C and D, and operations X, Y and Z. The objective is to write code that will test all combinations (within a certain range) of A, B, C and D, and possibly change the operations X, Y or Z.

This would be simple if it was just a matter of placing variables within a certain range. But since I want to also change operators, it is not as simple.

My idea is to write the code that would cover all combinations. For example, lets consider that there are only two parameters (A and B) and that the range is the same for both: [1,2], integers. The code would build (and if possible, execute) 4 different executables, corresponding to use the algorithm with:

```
A = 1, B = 1
A = 1, B = 2
A = 2, B = 1
A = 2, B = 2
```

Now adding the operators. For example, we pick the previous example and add operation X, where it can be [+,-]. The resulting set is:

```
A = 1, B = 1, X = +
A = 1, B = 2, X = -
A = 2, B = 1, X = +
A = 2, B = 2, X = -
A = 1, B = 1, X = -
A = 1, B = 2, X = +
A = 2, B = 1, X = -
A = 2, B = 2, X = +
```

(I hope I wrote all combinations)

Anyway, I believe it is possible to build such structure using a makefile, where it attributes values to constants of a code written in C. I am not sure that is possible to change the operators in such way. I was thinking of using a makefile for simplicity. It is always possible to write code that generates code, but seems quite exaggerated for the case.

Perhaps it would create a tree structure? I'm not sure if it is beneficial to have (and picking the first example):

```
|--Makefile
|--A1
|   |--B1
|   |   |--a.out
|   |--B2
|       |--a.out
|--A2
    |--B1
    |  |--a.out
    |--B2
        |--a.out
```

Using make I believe I can add extra variables/operators to the code and rebuild all the tests easily. Also, does this structure allow the use of the jobs functionality of make in order to have multiple threads running?

Thanks

Comment: On SO, you're supposed to show an effort and give evidence that you've tried something already and ask why it didn't work. SO users don't write your code for you.

Comment: I am not asking for code. I am asking such idea is possible, specially the part where it generates automatically executables with different operators. I will make that clear then, so you can remove your downvote.

Comment: Just off the top of my head, if you have some arrays containing the possible values you could just loop through all of them. Think of it as a combination lock. You loop through the first array, and inside you loop through the second array, etc. Then, in the final loop, you run the executable.

Comment: As I said on the question, for variables that is basic. The hard part is making the code have different operators automatically.

Comment: You said you have executables right? Otherwise use functions? In any case, if the operations are the same each time, you can just call `system` or `popen` to run executables in the final loop or call a function etc. You could pass arguments to change the operations each time.

Comment: I don't have executables, I wanted to create executables that run the algorithm. The operations are always the same on each executable, but each executable is supposed to have different operations. What I want (and apparently this not clear) is to generate executables using the same code, but whereas one has a sum the other has a subtraction (for example).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93161/discussion-between-arc676-and-camandros).

Comment: I would suggest some kind of array of function pointers with void * input parameters. That way you can loop through the function pointers which have arbitrary type size etc.

Comment: How would that allow me to generate two executables, one with += and the other with -=?

Comment: suggest:  use an external file that the code reads to determine the order, etc of the operations.   Such a file would be simple to modify. (or extend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method I've used in the past:

You can write a shell script to define a macro and *then* compile the program. Using this method, you can write just one source file and compile multiple programs. Example program that performs some operation on two numbers passed in via command line args:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv[]){
    if (argc != 3){ //takes just 2 numbers (for example purposes)
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: prog num1 num2\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int a = (int)strtol(argv[1], (char**)NULL, 10);
    int b = (int)strtol(argv[2], (char**)NULL, 10);
    int c = a MySpecialOperation b;
    printf("%d %s %d = %d\n", a, MySpecialOperationText, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

You will quickly notice that `MySpecialOperation` and `MySpecialOperationText` are undefined. This is intentional. (Also the program assumes that the command line args are valid.)

Now let's say you want 4 programs that perform the 4 basic arithmetic operations. Write a script to compile your program (this is in BASh):

```
echo \#define MySpecialOperation \+ > tmp.c
echo \#define MySpecialOperationText \"plus\" >> tmp.c
cat myprogram.c >> tmp.c
gcc tmp.c -o addition_prog
echo \#define MySpecialOperation \- > tmp.c
echo \#define MySpecialOperationText \"minus\" >> tmp.c
cat myprogram.c >> tmp.c
gcc tmp.c -o subtraction_prog
echo \#define MySpecialOperation \* > tmp.c
echo \#define MySpecialOperationText \"times\" >> tmp.c
cat myprogram.c >> tmp.c
gcc tmp.c -o multiplication_prog
echo \#define MySpecialOperation \/ > tmp.c
echo \#define MySpecialOperationText \"divided by\" >> tmp.c
cat myprogram.c >> tmp.c
gcc tmp.c -o division_prog
rm tmp.c
```

This script automatically creates a *new file*, writes the preprocessor statement `#define` to it, defining the previously undefined variables, then appends the original source file to it. Now, the compiler will replace `MySpecialOperation` with the operation (`+`,`-`,`*`, or `/`) and `MySpecialOperationText` with the appropriate word, and the code will compile and perform that operation.

Comment: Thanks. Now I will try to write some sort of make with it.